# Nomenclature for components of a Gauge UI element

Tags: conventions, naming

Are there any standard / common names for the components of a Gauge or Donut UI element? This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

The components I'm interested in are:

- The background gray area - what would be called a "track" in a scrollbar
- The foreground yellow area
- Other components - the Min, Max and Current value labels (*obvious names here*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving from Apple's UIProgressView documentation;

- The foreground yellow area is called progress,
- The background gray area is called track,
- Other components may be called as limits, current progress.

Here is the link if you want to see the full documentation: [UIProgressView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).